# Ember.js get controller in view

Tags: ember.js

I feel like this should be pretty straight-forward, but I'm unable to get the contents of a controller in a different view.  Here is my code:

```
App.MapView = Ember.View.extend({
    elementId: ['map-canvas'],
    didInsertElement: function() {
        var self = this;
        var controller = this.get('controllers.markers');
    }
});
```

If I console.log(controller) I get undefined.

In a controller I would do something like:

```
App.MarkersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    needs: ['map']
});
App.MapController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
   plot: function() {
      var markers = this.get('controllers.markers');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 9):

You place the needs on the controller that needs another controller, and where you'll be accessing the other controller.

And from a view, in order to grab the controller you do `this.get('controller')` and the `controllers` object lives on the controller, so `controller.controllers.markers`

Additionally, the view is only created with the controller by default if ember creates it, if you are doing something like `{{view App.MapView}}` it isn't creating the `MapController` and associating it with it, it's using the controller that was in scope when you created the view.

```
App.MapView = Ember.View.extend({
  elementId: ['map-canvas'],
  didInsertElement: function() {
    var self = this;
    var controller = this.get('controller.controllers.markers');
  }
});

App.MarkersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

});
App.MapController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['markers'],
  plot: function() {
   var markers = this.get('controllers.markers');
  }
});
```

Check out this implementation of it:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ODuZibod/1/edit

Comment: I think if I use var controller = this.get('controller.controllers.markers.model') I almost get what I need... but I can't figure out how to loop through the contents. If it helps, I need to pull the contents of the markers controller, loop through them in the view, and then create a Google Maps marker for each.  I would have just done all of this in a controller or model, but I think the didInsertElement within a view is the best place to do this as I know that the map has been created...

Comment: I also have {{#view App.MapView contentBinding="controllers.markers"}}{{/view}} which should be passing in my markers to my view, right?  If that's correct, how would I access the content binding within didInsertElement?

Comment: var markers = this.get('controller.controllers.markers') || this.get('content'); if it's going to be one or the other

Comment: console.log(controller = this.get('content')); displays the following output http://cl.ly/image/1Z0v2x1I2e3l  

How would I go about looping through that?  controller.forEach(function(item){ console.log(item) }); displays nothing.

Ideally I could do something like:

controller.forEach(function(item){ 
    // create marker by accessing item.mapLat, item.mapLong
});

Additionally, if I run $.each(controller, function(key, value){ console.log(value) }); I get everything defined on value